# C# - Decodificar array JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Preciso pegar o `id` desse código `JSON` usando `C#`:

> `[{"nome":"Gabriel Ferreira","cidade":"São Paulo","uf":"SP","id":"4274892"}]`

Alguém pode me aconselhar como posso fazer isso da melhor forma, pois já tentei com `JSON.net` da seguinte forma:

```
public class pegarID    
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string uf { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
pegarID pegarid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pegarID>(responseString);
Console.WriteLine(pegarid.id);
```

Porém não funcionou...

Comment: Aconteceu alguma exceção? Se sim, qual foi? Se não, _o que_ não funcionou? A propriedade veio vazia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JSON que você está tentando converter é uma `coleção`, não um objeto único. (Note os colchetes "[" e "]" no texto)

Tente

```
public class pegarID
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cidade { get; set; }
    public string uf { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
pegarID[] colecaoPegarid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<pegarID[]>(responseString);

Console.WriteLine(colecaoPegarid[0].id);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fonte: http://json.org/